# SQL group: count multiple things

Tags: mysql, sql

Right now I've got the following (My)SQL-Statement which returns the amount of entrys based on hour.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS amount
    HOUR(date) AS hour
    -- [1]
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    HOUR(date)
```

But I actually want another result that contains the amount of days the hour appeared. Basicly something like:

```
[1] = COUNT(DAY(date), MONTH(date), YEAR(date)) AS day_count
```

Example:

```
id  |   date
0   |   01/01/2001 5:15
1   |   01/01/2001 5:10
2   |   01/01/2001 6:03
3   |   01/01/2001 7:04
4   |   02/01/2001 5:00
```

Should return

```
amount  |   hour    |   day_count
3       |   5       |   2
1       |   6       |   1
1       |   7       |   1
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected results?  Not completely understanding your question.

Comment: Okay, I added an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to part out the days by hour and day, and group by them...

```
SELECT count(*) as `amount`
     , count(hour(date)) as `Hour`
     , count(day(date)) as `Day_Count`
FROM table 
GROUP BY hour(Date), day(date)
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work! But I think `day(01/01/2001)` = `day(01/02/2001)` = 1, so I group by month and year as well.

Comment: Ah yes; it would.  I assumed you were just doing some thing day over day hour over hour and didn't care about the month/year.